when using ggplot2 package, problem of disappearing a world map filtered data
When using geom_sf, there is an issue with country maps disappearing when using filters. How can I prevent countries from disappearing from the world map?
whole data
ggplot(data = df_mg23exp ) +
geom_sf(aes(fill = dollars),na.rm=FALSE) +
xlab("Long") + ylab("Lat") +
ggtitle("World map", subtitle = paste0("(", length(unique(df_c$name_en)), 
"countries)"))+
scale_fill_viridis_c(labels = scales::label_dollar(),trans = "sqrt", option = 
"C",na.value="#3b3b3b") -> fig23exp_

fig23exp_


filtering data
ggplot() +
geom_sf(data = df_mg23exp %>% filter(cd1name=="arts"), aes(fill 
=dollars),na.rm=FALSE) 
+  xlab("Long") + ylab("Lat") +
ggtitle("World map", subtitle = paste0("(", length(unique(df_c$name_en)), " 
countries)"))+
scale_fill_viridis_c(labels = scales::label_dollar(),trans = "sqrt", option =     
"C",na.value="#3b3b3b")  -> fig23exp_arts

fig23exp_arts



If cd1name != "arts" for a given country, then it will not appear in the map. Check the cd1name values of the missing countries. Without a minimal, reproducible example, it's hard to say for sure but that the most likely cause. Please update your question with more information about your dataset.
